# Remove/Delete .htaccess 301 permanent redirection from Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.8

I copy my live site and create development site and from development site I want to remove .htaccess redirection for that I go to .htaccess (root file) and delete all redirect code but still it's redirect me to live site url.

For ex : 
live site url is : example.com

dev site url is : dev.example.com

now I have **test** category and I go to that category then it's url should be 
**dev.example.com/test.html** but it's redirect me to **example.com/test.html** because in .htaccess file redirection is defind so I have removed all redirection code but still it's redirect me to live site url.

I have cleared cache and rename var/cache folder but still not getting output.

Answer (score 0):

Magento rewrite rule store in database and based on that it will be redirect. Make you sure that you are checking in dev category.